# Which MIME type to return?

Tags: javascript, content-type, mime-types

I have an HTML page with a JavaScript code that sends AJAX request. The request is being handled by my servlet. I've thought that it's "better" and "more correct" to return the data as "application/json" MIME type from the servlet (response content type). However, it drives MSIE crazy - meaning the browser seems not to be capable to display/process this MIME type (Chrome/FF are just fine). When I specify no type explicitly - it works fine in all browsers. Is it real that no MIME type should be returned from servlet for AJAX requests?

**Update:** my server side is implemented in Java and the MIME type is being defined by a following line:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```

the response is the following text (only an example):

```
{ "status" : "DONE", "progress" : 100, "url" : "/7909118672283641787.docx" , "totalBytes" : 17696 }
```

**Update2:** the snippet made of my client-side code (plain javascript, no libraries)

```
function display_progress(http) {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        var again = false;

        if (http.status != 200) {
            document.getElementById('progress_bar').innerHTML = "Wrong response status received: " + http.status + "! Fix the server-side code.";
        } else {
            try {
                var resp = eval('(' + http.responseText + ')');             
                var status = resp['status'];

                if (status == 'DOING') {
                    document.getElementById('progress_bar').innerHTML = "Uploaded: " + resp['progress'] + "%";
                    again = true;
                } else if (status == 'DONE'){
                    document.getElementById('progress_bar').innerHTML = 
                        "Uploaded 100% (" + resp['totalBytes'] + " bytes)! Your file is <a href=\"" + resp['url'] + "\"/>" + "here" + "</a>";
                } else if (status == 'ERROR') {
                    document.getElementById('progress_bar').innerHTML = "Error while uploading!";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('progress_bar').innerHTML = "Unexpected state: " + status + "! Fix the server-side code.";
                }
            } catch (ex) {
                document.getElementById('progress_bar').innerHTML = "Wrong response received: " + resp + "! Fix the server-side code.";
            }
        }

        if (again) {
            setTimeout("update_progress()", 500);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What code are you using exactly to handle the response?

Comment: JSON data should be served as `application/json`.  If something is not working, the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: No, I mean what code are you using to handle it on client side? What breaks exactly?

Comment: @Pekka: please see the update2. Nothing breaks actually, it's just that the status on the progress bar is not updated.

Comment: `setTimeout("update_progress()", 500);` should be `setTimeout(update_progress, 500);`.  This will avoid evaling the string.  Also as per @user400908's answer, you should use `JSON.parse` instead of `eval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained here: http://www.entwicklungsgedanken.de/2008/06/06/problems-with-internet-explorer-and-applicationjson/ `text/javascript` is the correct workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Return it as raw text then use `JSON.parse()` to convert to JSON that is useable.

JSON is not text, so Firefox doesn't know WHAT to do with it. Therefore, you need to basically serve it as something it does know.

Comment: just added the raw text I am constructing on the fly

Comment: Not all browsers have `JSON`.  You may need to use json2.js from here: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 0):

No this is not true....you can set MIME types for AJAX requests...in case you are not setting them...they take the default value....which happens to be...."text/plain". 
So I guess the default is working fine for you....A more common response type happens to be "text/html". It all depends on the code that you will be using to handle the response from the servlet...the problem may lie in that part of the code....

Comment: (on default value) more correct is: which happens to be... whatever the webserver is configured for. Popular types include text/plain, text/html and application/octet-stream.

Comment: @T-Bull Thank You for the correction...My lecturer at college taught me that..will take up with him...

Comment: just added some example in the question body - any idea on what I am doing wrong?